# How to identify if bluetooth device is an app user in Java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm building an android app that allow phone to discuss via bluetooth in Java. So i make the device discoverable and i do a discovery to find the device arround me.

Is their a simple way to know if a device found was made discoverable by my app without having to paire both device ?

Make the device discoverable :

```
int requestCode = 1;
    Intent discoverableIntent =
            new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, requestCode);
```

Comment: Not using Bluetooth CLassic as far as I am aware. This would be possible using Bluetooth Low Energy by filtering for devices that offer your custom BLE service.

Comment: Have you tried advertising custom data from your advertiser app, and checking that custom advertising data in your discovering app side?